# Simple Delete Command in SQL giving error message

Tags: sql, openoffice-base

I'm fairly new to SQL (I learned it just yesterday). The DBMS application I am using is OpenOffice.org Base on Windows 10.

I created a table in my DBMS by the name of Employees, with several records. The Primary Key is EmployeeID (I'll attach a screenshot of the table for reference).

The problem is when I try to execute a code to delete the record with the EmployeeID "E001", I get an error message.

Code:

```
DELETE FROM "Employees"
WHERE "EmployeeID" = "E001";
```

This code seems simple enough to me. However, this is the error message I get:

```
1: Column not found: E001
```

I expected this to work, because I tried to use it on the w3schools.com online editor, and it worked (with a different database). I'll leave a link to it down below.

If this problem is exclusive to OOo Base, I can't do anything about it, since I need to use it for a school assignment.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Employees Table]

[w3schools.com Online Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_delete)

Comment: String literal values should usually be defined in **single quotes** : `... WHERE "EmployeeID" = 'E001'`; - double quotes denote table and column names

Comment: Use single qoutes in literals 'E001'

Answer (score 2):

Quotes in a RDBMS are typically used for different purposes, as described in the comments above.

String literal values are always contained in 'single quotes', double quotes are typically needed as *delimiters* to identify object names where the name contains one of several non-standard characters or clashes with the name of a reserved word.

So double quotes are not necessary when naming a table Employees - but would be if for example the table's name was "order" since *order* is also a reserved keyword, or "Employee Status" since it contains a space.

Some databases have their own specific delimiters either instead of or an addition to double quotes, such as MySql which uses `backticks` or SQL Server that uses [square brackets].